# Getting bad request error on forn submission in react

Tags: reactjs

This the component I created. I can get the contact in `console` but throws error on submission. I can post the data through Postman; the problem occurs when I submit the form. Where is the error in the `handlesubmit` function?

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const ContactForm = () => {
  const [contact, setContact] = useState({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    phoneNumber: '',
    email: '',
    message: '',
  });

  function handleChange(e) {
    setContact({ ...contact, [e.target.name]: [e.target.value] });
  }

  function hanhdleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(contact);

    axios
      .post('http://localhost:8080/contact', contact)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('Response after post api', response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error while post api', error);
      });
  }

  return (
    <div className="box poptrox-popup  ">
      <form onSubmit={hanhdleSubmit} noValidate>
        <div className="row gtr-uniform">
          <div className="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="First Name"
              value={contact.firstName}
              name="firstName"
              onChange={handleChange}
              autoComplete="off"
            />
            <br />
          </div>
          <div className="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Last Name"
              value={contact.lastName}
              name="lastName"
              onChange={handleChange}
              autoComplete="off"
            />
            <br />
          </div>
          <div className="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
            <input
              type="tel"
              placeholder="Phone Number"
              value={contact.phoneNumber}
              name="phoneNumber"
              onChange={handleChange}
              autoComplete="off"
            />
            <br />
          </div>
          <div className="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
            <input
              type="email"
              placeholder="Email"
              value={contact.email}
              name="email"
              onChange={handleChange}
              autoComplete="off"
            />
            <br />
          </div>
          <div className="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
            <textarea
              placeholder="Please type what you are looking from us?"
              value={contact.message}
              name="message"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <br />
          </div>

          <div className="col-12">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>

            <h1>First Name:{contact.firstName}</h1>
            <h1>Last Name:{contact.lastName}</h1>
            <h1>Phone Number:{contact.phoneNumber}</h1>
            <h1>Email:{contact.email}</h1>
            <h1>message:{contact.message}</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
export default ContactForm;
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```json
{
  "timestamp": "2020-12-04T18:32:39.945+00:00",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "",
  "path": "/contact"
}
```

Comment: In the onChange youre setting the value to { ...contact, [e.target.name]: [e.target.value] }` Should that be ` { ...contact, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }` The post is sending the values wrapped in brackets...

Comment: Yes worked it for me  Zsolt,thanks a lot for your replay

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the syntax of the body sent to the backend, the second parameter of your axios.post should be an object :

```
axios
      .post('http://localhost:8080/contact', contact)
```

should be

```
axios
      .post('http://localhost:8080/contact', { contact })
```

Comment: let me know if this was the issue

Comment: its not  Marc ,i have tried it before submitting its becauseset Contact({...contact, [e.target.name] : [e.target.value] })  i was putting [] in e.target.name .thanks for your reply.